# Can I use Nutch 2.x and Gora with a Solr backend

Tags: solr, nutch, gora

The Nutch 2.x branch `gora.properties` file lists Solr as a possible backend for Nutch, but I cannot find any documentation online. So, two questions:

1. Can I do this: `Nutch -> Gora -> Solr`, and use SOLR for both storage and indexing? I can't find any documentation on this particular setup.
2. Is there any benefit to doing this: `Nutch -> Gora -> HBase -> Solr`, where Solr is only used to index HBase. This seems to be the most common approach, but HBase seems unnecessary if the main goal is to consume the results with Solr.

Here is the 2.x [gora.properties](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/conf/gora.properties):

```
############################
# SolrStore properties     #
############################
#gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.solr.store.SolrStore
#gora.solrstore.solr.url=http://localhost:9876/solr
#gora.solrstore.solr.config=solrconfig.xml
#gora.solrstore.solr.schema=gora-solr-schema.xml
#gora.solrstore.solr.batchSize=100
#gora.solrstore.solr.solrjserver=http
#gora.solrstore.solr.commitWithin=1000
#gora.solrstore.solr.resultsSize=100
```

Comment: I opened a ticket in Nutch related to this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2113

Comment: I also opened a ticket for a missing dependency when building Nutch with a SOLR backend: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2112